# Sorting of pivot table: Not sorted correctly

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

After creating a pivot table based on ticker symbol on new sheet, I am getting first three entries (MON, MAR, NOV) that are not sorted when ascending sort option applied.

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel has an internal Custom Lists that it uses while sorting pivot tables. The Custom Lists take precedence over other items. Among the items on the Custom Lists are months and days. Excel interprets the first 3 items of your list as days or months (MON = Monday, MAR = March, NOV = November). That is why they are the first items after sorting even if alphabetically they should not be.

To sort the pivot table correctly for your case:

- Right-click on a cell of the pivot table, then select PivotTable Options

[image: Right-click - Pivot table option]

- Open the Data tab. On the Sorting section, uncheck Use Custom Lists when sorting. Click OK.

Your pivot table will now be sorted correctly.

[image]